# preferences-company-wide setting does not work in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, preferences, portlet, sharing

I created 2 test portlets, myportlet1 and myportlet2. Both descriptions are similiar and looks like this in `portlet.xml`

```xml
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>myportlet1</portlet-name>
    <display-name>MyPortlet1</display-name>
    <portlet-class>com.inthemoon.tests.MyPortlet1</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>view-jsp</name>
        <value>/html/myportlet1/view.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>
    </supports>
    <portlet-info>
        <title>MyPortlet1</title>
        <short-title>MyPortlet1</short-title>
        <keywords></keywords>
    </portlet-info>
    <portlet-preferences>
        <preference>
            <name>testPreferenceForMyPortlet1</name>
            <value>C:\WINDOWS1</value>
        </preference>
    </portlet-preferences>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
</portlet>
```

and like this in `liferay-portlet.xml`

```xml
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>myportlet1</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>
    <preferences-company-wide>true</preferences-company-wide>
    <instanceable>false</instanceable>
    <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>
        /js/main.js
    </footer-portlet-javascript>
    <css-class-wrapper>myportlet1-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
</portlet>
```

the difference is with index.

So, as you see, both portlets are not instanceable and set to share their preferences company-wide.

Although, the following code shows that each portlet knows only it's own preferences but not other portlet's ones:

```
@Override
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest,
        RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

    javax.portlet.PortletPreferences prefs1 = renderRequest.getPreferences();
    //com.liferay.portal.model.PortletPreferences prefs2 = PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.

    String portletResource = ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "portletResource");
    if (Validator.isNotNull(portletResource)) {
        try {
            prefs1 = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletSetup(renderRequest, portletResource);
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String testPreferenceForMyPortlet1 = prefs1.getValue("testPreferenceForMyPortlet1", "(not set)");
    String testPreferenceForMyPortlet2 = prefs1.getValue("testPreferenceForMyPortlet2", "(not set)");

    renderRequest.setAttribute("testPreferenceForMyPortlet1", testPreferenceForMyPortlet1);
    renderRequest.setAttribute("testPreferenceForMyPortlet2", testPreferenceForMyPortlet2);

    renderRequest.setAttribute("prefs1", prefs1);

    super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}
```

What did I did wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Problem' is that `preferences-company-wide` does not tells that preferences will be shared with different portlets.

It's usage is for sharing preferences within single portlet but in different communities/organizations/user_pages ... (different group id's).

To get preferences of another portlet you would have to use

```
PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletSetup(portletRequest, "another portlet's id");
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I use IDs seen in portletpreferences table, for example "LIFERAY_PORTAL" for very global setting?

Comment: I did not try it, but form source it seems so, but for that purpose than it's better to use PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortalPreferences(portletRequest); Take note "getPortal" instead of "getPortlet".